# How to add a new module to existing project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I am using WebStorm. I already have an empty project open within which I have about 10 projects added.

This was done in the past. I wish to add one more.

Previously I added these by going into Project Structure and adding a new module.

But I can no longer see this option. Please see screenshot.

How can I see project Structure in WebStorm so that I can add a new module to my existing project setup? Thanks.

WebStorm version: 2020.3.2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new project to an existing project, go to File -> Open... and then find the directory you'd like to add. Click Open on the file dialog, and then WebStorm will ask you how you'd like to handle opening the project. Select Attach.

[image: WebStorm Open Dialog]